# Upgrade from Wildfly 10 to Wildfly 14 Infinispan issue

Tags: wildfly, infinispan

We have migrated from Widlfly 10 to Wildfly 14. We have an issue with our configuration for the Infinispan(7.0) web cache-container . In previous versions its was possible to set a mode to ASYNC. This is no longer possible and the documenation states:

> Deprecated Since 6.0.0 Deprecated. This attribute will be ignored. All
>   cache modes will be treated as SYNC. To perform asynchronous cache
>   operations, use Infinispan's asynchronous cache API.

[https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/14.0/subsystem/infinispan/cache-container/distributed-cache/index.html](https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/14.0/subsystem/infinispan/cache-container/replicated-cache/index.html)

**We do not want to have the mode SYNC that now is default so how can we by configuring standalone-ha.xml use Infinispan's asynchronous cache API?**

Wildfly 10 config

```
    <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
        <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
        <distributed-cache name="dist" mode="ASYNC" l1-lifespan="0" owners="2">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            <file-store/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="concurrent" mode="SYNC" l1-lifespan="0" owners="2">
            <file-store/>
        </distributed-cache>
</cache-container>
```

Wildfly 14 config

```
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <distributed-cache name="dist">
                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store/>
            </distributed-cache>
        </cache-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WF 14, modifications to the session cache are committed after the response is flushed - so all cache access is effectively asynchronous from the perspective of the user.

Additionally, ASYNC cache mode is not the same as Infinispan's async cache API.

The async cache API is only relevant to SYNC cache modes.

Same question was asked in the WildFly forum. See https://developer.jboss.org/thread/279453

Comment: Do you know if the lock is aquired once the transaction starts in the container and released only once the response is flushed? If so, is this a new behavior compared to the previous async mode behavior. We are seeing trouble with very long response times.